# Jetpack Compose how to build custom Color by overlaying 2 existing colors in code?

Tags: kotlin, colors, android-jetpack-compose

Designers often building custom colors by putting existing colros from "our" custom theme one of top of another with alpha applied.
How can I calculate resulting Color without applying multiple backgrounds one of top of another?
Something like

```
val background = MaterialTheme.colors.MyDanger.copy(alpha = 0.12f) + MaterialTheme.colors.CustomTint16
```

Plus is not defined for Colors as it's not Commutative, but is there a way to just put one Color on top on another in Code and apply only result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val result = color1.compositeOver(color2)
```

Is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Example1:**

```
// Ratio value has to be 0.5 to achive even mix.
//The 3rd argument is ratio(the proportion while blending the colors). eg. 
//If you want 30% of color1 & 70% of color2, then do ColorUtils.blendARGB(***, ***, 0.3F); 
int resultColor = androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils.blendARGB(color1, color2, 0.5F);
```

**Example2:**

```
public static int mixColor(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverse = 1 - ratio;
    float a = (color1 >>> 24) * inverse + (color2 >>> 24) * ratio;
    float r = ((color1 >> 16) & 0xFF) * inverse + ((color2 >> 16) & 0xFF) * ratio;
    float g = ((color1 >> 8) & 0xFF) * inverse + ((color2 >> 8) & 0xFF) * ratio;
    float b = (color1 & 0xFF) * inverse + (color2 & 0xFF) * ratio;
    return ((int) a << 24) | ((int) r << 16) | ((int) g << 8) | (int) b;
}
```

Comment: I don't want half1 and half2. I need to draw color2 on top of color1. Both are semi transparent. This will make resulted Color the background should be.

Comment: And this is for android.graphics.Color. Compose have it's own compose.Color, very similar.
ColorUtils.composeColors() is what I need, but for compose colors.

Comment: Oh, and your question doesn't mention that both are translucent

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made this implementation on top of `ColorUtils.blendARGB`.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils

fun Color.blend(topColor: Color, ratio: Float = 0.5f): Color {
    if (ratio == 0f) return this
    if (ratio == 1f) return topColor
    val intColor = ColorUtils.blendARGB(toArgb(), topColor.toArgb(), ratio)
    return Color(intColor)
}
```

And usage (add a little extra green to background):

```
modifier = Modifier
    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background.blend(Green200))
```

---

Actually, `.compositeOver()` do the same, but in weird way: it is extension for extraColor. You should write `extraColor.compositeOver(mainColor)`. And not useful in case when you need to add extraColor conditionally.

Also, `compositeOver` not support proportions (`ratio` in my suggested extension).

But finally, code on `extraColor.compositeOver(mainColor)` is the same as `mainColor.blend(extraColor, 0.5f)`.